# HTML code is not working in Blade Template in Laravel

Tags: laravel-blade

Here is the code of View in laravel, Here i am using blade template.
The problem is that $paymentstatus ouput isn't showing up propery, it shows html code in the browser, please help me out to solve this problem.

```
<tbody>
@php
$count=1;
@endphp
@foreach($orders as $c)
<?php

if($c->payment_status==0){
    $paymentstatus='<span class="label label-danger">Unpaid</span>';
}
else{
    $paymentstatus='Paid';
}


if($c->status==0)
    $status='Hold';
if($c->status==1)
    $status='Complete';

?>
<tr>
<td>{{$count++}}.</td>
<td>{{$c->name}}</td>
<td>{{$c->order_weight}} Kg</td>
<td>{{$c->order_type}}</td>
<td>Rs. {{$c->amount}}</td>
<td>{{$paymentstatus}}</td>
<td>{{$status}}</td>
<td>
<div class="btn-group">
<select name="action" class="form-control">
<option>Select Action</option>
<option value="1">Complete</option>
<option value="2">Pay</option>
<option value="3">Complete & Pay</option>
</select>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button><!--{{Form::close()}}-->
</div>
</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use ..

Laravel blade own if else
`@if()` `@else` `@endif`

if you want to use php if-else..
so use 
`@php` 
instead of 
`<?php` and `@endphp` instead of `?>`

because `<?php` not worked in blade template.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is when your payment status is 0, it renders

that html as text, blade engine understand that as a string

You can do the following:

```
<td> 
 @if($c->payment_status==0) 
   <span class="label label-danger">Unpaid</span>
 @else 
   <span class="label label-success">Paid</span>
 @endif
</td>
```